# Rerun same code but changing colums names at each loop

Tags: r, loops, dplyr, apply

I have a script in r to calculate body condition residuals. I would like to apply this code to each columns, which correspond to a specific category of individual.

For example i would run this code to calculate body condition residuals of all individuals that are in the category 1

1)  Select rows of interest

```
Data1 = RawData %>% select(ID,temperature, Bodysize1, mass1, year) %>%  filter((temperature %in% c(20:29) & Bodysize1 %in% c(20:100) & mass1 %in% c(15:40))
```

2)  Create a new model with created data

```
Model1 =lmer(log(mass1) ~ log(Bodysize1) + temperature + (1|year), data = Data1)
```

3)  Extract residuals and add ID to the residuals

```
ResModel1 = resid(Model1)
ID=Data1$ID
Res1 =data.frame(ResModel1 ,ID)
```

4)  Add residuals to my RawData

```
RawData2.0 = merge(RawData, Res1, by = c("ID"), all.x = T)
```

In order to avoid reruning this code and manually changing all the 1 by 2 and then all the 2 by 3... etc is there a way to do this commande automatic whith loops and the apply familly?

My data

```
  ID        TEMPERATURE  BODYSIZE1 MASS1 BODYSIZE2 MASS2    YEAR
81-012       0.03830645     200    1450     205    1425     1981
84-069       0.26923078     200    1473     205    1498     1984
84-134       0.32692307     209    1448     195    1323     1984
84-145       0.27884614     197    1373     197    1498     1984
84-190       0.31129807     191    1248     195    1323     1984
85-155       0.33056709     198    1637     229    1988     1985
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Withou example data it is tough to say if this will work but maybe creating a function can simplify your workflow

library(tidyverse)

```
get_resid <- function(df,filters) {

df_to_model <- df %>% filter({{filters}})
df_to_keep <- df <- filter({{filters}},.preserve = FALSE)

Data1 <-  df_to_model %>%
  select(ID,temperature, Bodysize1, mass1, year)

Model1 <- lmer(log(mass1) ~ log(Bodysize1) + temperature + (1|year), data = Data1)


ResModel1 <-  resid(Model1)
ID <- Data1$ID
Res1 <- data.frame(ResModel1 ,ID)

Res1 %>% 
  bind_rows(df_to_keep)

}
```

Then you may use this this function in your pipes

```
RawData %>% 
  get_resid(temperature %in% c(20:29) & Bodysize1 %in% c(20:100) & mass1 %in% c(15:40))
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer sadly i got this error message: Error in filter({ : object 'temperature' not found

Comment: You are probably suffering from problems with quasiquotation, this is really hard to debug without the data

Answer (score 0):

You might try to i) create a tibble, in the first column list all dep variables as strings, 
ii) list your models of indep vars in the second column, 
iii) create a formula in the third column
iv) run your model in the fourth column

```
df <- tibble(dep = paste0("log(var",seq(1,10,1),")"),
             x = "~ your_x_vars") %>%
  mutate(formula = as.formula(paste0(dep,x))) %>%
  mutate(reg = map(formula, ~lm(as.formula(.x), data=df) ))
```

then you can easily extract the residuals